# Feynman lecture 2, 36-6: How $\mu_{z}$ change with iron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, ferromagnetism

https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_36.html#mjx-eqn-EqII367
[image]

Feynman assumes nickel instead of iron. Without changing other assumptions, how $\mu_{z}$ change its form in case of iron?

- And how can I derive Lande g factor of iron?